# Asp.net mvc not connecting to SQL Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2012, asp.net-identity

I created an asp.net mvc project using the built in account controller (asp.net identity).

On my local host everything works great but when I publish it I get an error

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

What confuses me is the fact that if I try to login with a bad password it acts normal and says wrong password so I guess it can access the database but when I put in a good password it crashes as quoted above.

Has anyone seen this before?

I have read this http://www.sswug.org/articlesection/default.aspx?TargetID=44331
and it seems to me that all is right.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The default instance will probably use LocalDB or sql express .. you might want to check your connection string to be sure its pointing to the right thing at the deployed instance

Comment: Ty for the answer, My connection string <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Server=resident.mssql.somee.com;Database=resident;user id=pkak112_SQLLogin_1;password=****;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />. I think it is good. If it uses a default how does it know when the user password is correct? @scartag

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: Where are you publishing it to? And does that server have network access to the SQL server?

Comment: Are you using free account on somee.com. If so then there are some limitations on database. I've had this issue a lot due to my database mdf file size was 22MB but somee only allows 20MB. So it would not login or throw any error. Change your hosting and everything will work fine.